# How to add database to Heroku (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have database in ROR app. What are the commands I should execute so that my database can work? I upload my application on Heroku yet. But I want to have database. (postgresql)

```
   development:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: Nature
      host: localhost
      username: postgres
      password: -----
      encoding: utf8


    test:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/test.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

    production:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/production.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
```

Comment: for starters your production db cannot be `sqlite` other than than your question is very vague. Try [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Comment: Heroku explains it pretty well at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#use-postgres. And I would recommend using postgres for your local dev instead of sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `postgresql` as your database adapter as mentioned on [**heroku**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#use-postgres). After that replace `gem 'sqlite'`with `gem 'pg'` in your gemfile and run `bundle install`.

As I know, heroku don't use database settings mentioned in database.yml for production, however, you may set production database as:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production_db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Push you updated code to heroku and heroku will create database for your app there.

Also, you can [pull/push database](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku) from/to heroku.